# Cropping with avconv

Tags: libav

I am trying to crop a video with avconv

```
avconv -r 25 -i test.avi -vf "crop=out_w=in_w" -b 1024k test2.avi
```

but avconv tells me

```
Invalid chars '=in_w' at the end of expression 'out_w=in_w'
```

whatever things I do it seems it can not understand stuff after "out_w".

Where am I wrong?
Thanks!